# NASM hamming distance

Tags: assembly, nasm, hamming-code

I have written this assembly code to determine the hamming distance between two strings entered by a user. I am not familiar with assembly at all, and this is my first attempt aside from writing helloWorld.

I think the code should be correct aside from the printing of the distance between the two strings.

```
extern printf
extern sscanf
extern fscanf

section .data ; instatiating constants ( variables ) 

msg1: db "Enter string to be compared less than 256 characters:",10 ; db allocates 
                                                                ;space in memory
len1: equ $-msg1 

msg2 db "Enter another string to be compared:",10 ;
len2: equ $-msg2

count:  dd 0               ;for the hamming code loop
    ; another string for "hamming distance"
    ; maybe make an error message


section .bss ; reserve space for data
;;  the bss section typically includes all uninitialized variables, as
;;  well as uninitialized variables declared STATIC

input1:     resb 256    ; 256 is max length of buffer
input2:     resb 256    ; "                        "
length1:    resb 4      ; reserve length of first string
length2:    resb 4      ; reserve lenght of second string


section .text ; 

global main

main:


; access to the contents of a memory location
; requires square brackets around the address

;; any access to the address of a variable doesn't require brackets

            ; mov is
;; http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-ca        lls.html

;; Prompt user for input
mov     eax, 4      ; moves sys_call write to eax
mov     ebx, 1      ;moves std_out to ebx
mov     ecx, msg1
mov     edx, len1
int 0x80        ; could do 080h , calls kernel to write
;;
;;
;; Get user input
mov     eax, 3          ;Moves sys_call read to eax
mov     ebx, 0      ;Moves sys_call std_in to ebx
mov     ecx, input1     ; address of buffer
mov     edx, 255
int 0x80        ;length of buffer
;;
;;
;; Error checking
sub     eax,1       ;remove carriage return
mov     [length1], eax  ;save length of string

;; Prompt user for input
mov     eax, 4      ; moves sys_call write to eax
mov     ebx, 1      ;moves std_out to ebx
mov     ecx, msg2
mov     edx, len2
int     0x80        ; could do 080h , calls kernel to write
;;
;;
;; Get user input
mov     eax, 3          ;Moves sys_call read to eax
mov     ebx, 0      ;Moves sys_call std_in to ebx
mov     ecx, input2     ; address of buffer
mov     edx, 255
int     0x80        ;length of buffer
;;
;;
;; Error checking
sub     eax,1       ;remove carriage return
mov     [length2], eax  ;save length of string

loop:
mov     esi, input1               ; point to start of string1 
mov     edi, input2               ; point to start of string2

mov     eax,[length1]       ; compare string sizes 
mov     ebx,[length2]       ; and loop based on smallest 
cmp     eax,ebx         ; string size
jg      str2_Sml        ; string2 is smaller jump     

                ; string1 is smaller...
mov     ecx, eax            ; initialize count
jmp     L1_test         ; start the loop

str2_Sml:
mov     ecx, ebx            ; initialize count
jmp     L1_test         ; start the loop

L1_test:     
cmp     ecx,31          ; if there are more then 31 chars
jb      L1_top  
mov     ecx,31          ; fail safe


L1_top:

mov     al, [esi]               ; get a character from str1
mov     bl, [edi]               ; get a character from str2
inc     esi                     ; update str1 ptr
inc     edi         ; update str2 ptr

xor     al, bl          ; find the different bits   
mov     ah, 8           ; setup innerloop counter
L2_top:
dec     ah      ; decrement bit counter
jz      L1_cont     ; get new char to ham every
                ; 8 bits

shr     al,1        ; rotate string1 
jc      Bit_on      ; bit is on
jmp     L2_top      ; bit is off so re-loop         

Bit_on:
                ; we have a different bit
inc     dword [count]   ; inc ham count
jmp     L2_top      ; cont loop

L1_cont:
dec     ecx                     ; update char count
jnz     L1_top                  ; loop to top if more chars

;trying to print
```

I think this is where my error is :

```
mov     eax, 4      ; moves sys_call write to eax
mov     ebx, 1  ;moves std_out to ebx
mov     ecx,ecx
mov     edx, 255
int 0x80            ; calls kernel




exit:   
mov     eax, 1      ;exit
mov     ebx, 0      ;
int 0x80        ;kernel command
```

Comment: What error? Does it fail to build? Did you run it and get an error, or the wrong answer?

Comment: In the area you say you think you have a problem, you have `mov ecx,ecx`. Not only does this do nothing, but `ecx` contains a character count (probably `0` at this point). Shouldn't it be the address of a string you want to print for the upcoming `int 0x80`? I'm supposing you need to convert the computed hamming distance to an ASCII string and put that string's address in `ecx`.